# Using .scrollTop() for position:relative to fixed jquery event

Tags: jquery, css, function, scroll, position

i have say a 30px header on the top of my page, and it is in fixed position already. And I have a div box about 50px away from my header. So it is 80px away from the top of my browser. I'm trying to create a jquery event where this div box will stay in place while scrolling down until it hits the bottom of my header, then it will be a fixed position.

The problem I'm having is when I'm using .scrollTop(), it touches the top of my browser instead of the bottom of my header then it becomes fixed position. I've tried .scrollTop(30), but it just puts my page 30px down on page start and it won't let me scroll anywhere, it'll just jitter back to 30px.

This is my jquery function right now if someone can help me modify it?

Thanks!

```
    $(function() {
        var a = function() {
            var b = $(window).scrollTop();
        //I've tried $(window).scrollTop() + "30px"; and $(window).scrollTop(30);
            var d = $("#notification-anchor").offset().top;
            var c = $("#notification");
            if (b > d) {
                c.css({position:"fixed",top:"30px"});
            } else {
                if(b<=d){
                c.css({position:"relative",top:"0px"});
                }
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(a);a()
    });
```

Comment: How about `b = $(window).scrollTop() + 30` ?

Comment: hehe that was an easy fix! Thank you

Comment: Just a note: in javascript everything sorrounded by quotes is a string so adding it to a number would result in: `123 + "30px" = "12330px"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out from @Shedokan's comment.

Thanks!